# Show/Hide views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have added a UIView in IB (targetView) and have added 4 labels as subview to this. I have seen it in hierarchy as well.

I also have an outlet for this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *targetView;
```

I want to show hide this container view (to actually show/hide the 4 labels inside it)
I am writing

```
targetView.hidden = YES;
```

But for some reason, it is not working. 
Please help me.

Comment: Where are you setting the container view to hidden?

Comment: and are you sure that you linked your view in IB correctly to the "targetView" property/object? the code itself is right, the error may be in the link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely you have not connected your IBOutlet to the UIView in interface builder.